# TypeScript function argument generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a TypeScript function that accepts an array and returns a new function where the arguments have the types of the array.

In other words, it should be something like this:

```
type MyFunc = {
    <A>(arg: [A]): ((arg0: A) => any)
    <A, B>(arg: [A, B]): ((arg0: A, arg1: B) => any)
    <A, B, C>(arg: [A, B, C]): ((arg0: A, arg1: B, arg2: C) => any)
}
```

But for a variable number of inputs

#### Concrete examples

Here's some concrete examples (even though I'm looking for the general case):

```
type MyFuncA = (arg: [number]) => ((arg0: number) => any)
type MyFuncB = (arg: [string]) => ((arg0: string) => any)
type MyFuncC = (arg: [number, string]) => ((arg0: number, arg1: string) => any)
type MyFuncD = (arg: [number, string, bool]) => ((arg0: number, arg1: string, arg2: bool) => any)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest would be:

```
type MyFunc = <T extends readonly unknown[]>(args: T) => (...args: T) => unknown
```

It accepts an array of anything as `T`, and spreads that array over the arguments of the returned function with `...args: T`.

Usage:

```
declare const fn: MyFunc // pretend this function exists

const testA = fn([1, 'asd', true] as const)
// (args_0: 1, args_1: "asd", args_2: true) => unknown
```

Just note the `as const` is used here to force the argument to be a tuple type `[number, string, boolean]`, rather than an array type of `(number | string | boolean)[]`, since it needs the tuple to infer the order of the arguments. But providing any tuple type should work fine.

If you don't pass in a tuple, you will provide a spread array type which is better than nothing but not as useful:

```
const testA = fn([1, 'asd', true])
// (...args: (string | number | boolean)[]) => unknown
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.6.2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgYygXigHgCpQgA9gJkATAZygCcIBDMge2QBsQoUBrZRgd2QDaAXQB8ACjrUA5hQBcUXAEpMIqGIB0myTPlKVHZNz7IAsAChzZCKhaToqZhWBQAZsnlwkac+YfInUCROAIKYrshiAgCMADRQAOR0FGTxccDUiBBCUElQfk6K5gD0RVBlUAB6APxAA)

---

If you have a tuple type with names for each element, those names will even be reported as the argument names of the function!

```
const myTuple: [num: number, str: string, isAwesome: boolean] = [1, 'asd', true]
const testA = fn(myTuple)
// (num: number, str: string, isAwesome: boolean) => unknown
```

Which is neat.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.6.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgYygXigHgCpQgA9gJkATAZygCcIBDMge2QBsQoUBrZRgd2QDaAXQB8ACjrUA5hQBcUXAEpMIqGIB0myTPlKVHZNz7IAsAChzZCKhaToqZhWBQAZsnlwkac+YfInUAC2ILiIYCwQ8gLIiIHyMYEARhDUADRQTtTymQCWyFLpORQAgrwQFIyBkVCJjIwRdMhCmFACAIzpAOR0FGSd6cDUiBBCvo7OJE7FLW5iwaHhEIrmAPQrUBtQAHoA-EA)